# My result doesn't agree with results from online calculators

Tags: linear-programming

I'm doing an exercise about linear programming, but my answer doesn't agree with the answer from online calculators like [this](https://www.zweigmedia.com/RealWorld/simplex.html) and [this](http://comnuan.com/cmnn03/cmnn03004/cmnn03004.php). Below is the problem statement:
$$Minimize: u = 4x - 3y, s.t.$$
$$y \le -x + 1$$
$$y \le x + 1$$
$$y \ge 0$$

I found 3 corner: (-1,0), (0,1), (1,0) and min = -4 at (-1,0), but these calculators gives me the answer -3 at (0,1). Did I miss anything when solving this problem?

Comment: Your solution looks fine to me. BTW: you can use `\leq` to get $\leq$ and `\geq` to get $\geq$.

Comment: Were you perhaps entering $x\geq 0$ as a constraint as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The online calculators assume nonnegativity. If you write $x$ as the difference of two nonnegative numbers, your [first calculator](https://www.zweigmedia.com/RealWorld/simplex.html) gives the right answer

```
Minimize p = 4x1-4x2-3y subject to
x1-x2+y <= 1
-x1+x2+y <= 1
```